# sql join equals array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, join

I'm trying to build a compatibility system of products and their options.
Each product exist of multiple editions with each their own specifications.
Each option also has their very own set of specifications

The table relation is as followed

```
Edition | - < editionspec > - | Specification
Option  | - < optionspec  > - | Specification
```

editionspec is filled like this

```
Edition | Specification
2       | 1
2       | 5
2       | 13
3       | 1
3       | 5
3       | 12
```

optionspec is filled like this

```
Option | Specification
1      | 1
1      | 5
1      | 12
2      | 1
2      | 5
2      | 12
3      | 12
8      | 1
8      | 5
8      | 13
9      | 13
```

In this case i searching options compatible to edition 3.

- option 1 is valid because 1, 5 & 12 match
- option 2 is valid bacause 1, 5 & 12 match
- option 3 is valid because 12 match and 1 and 5 are null
- option 8 is invalid because 1 and 5 match but 13 also which doesnt belong to option 8.

! Some background information but i believe its inrelevant to the solution.

- 1 is in the group of Length specification (id: 1) (group contains id's 1, 2, 3 & 4)
- 5 is in the group of Height specifications (id: 2) (group contains id's 1, 2, 3, 4 & 5)
- 12 and 12 are in the group of seats specifications (id: 3) (group contains ids 12 & 13)

My query so far:

```
SELECT `o`.* FROM `option` AS `o`
LEFT JOIN `optionspec` AS `os` ON o.id = os.option
LEFT JOIN `specification` AS `s` ON os.specification = s.id
LEFT JOIN `editionspec` AS `es` ON s.id = es.specification
LEFT JOIN `edition` AS `e` ON es.edition = e.id
LEFT JOIN `productcompatibility` AS `pc` ON o.id = pc.option
LEFT JOIN `product` AS `p` ON pc.product = p.id
LEFT JOIN `edition` AS `e2` ON p.id = e2.product
LEFT JOIN `optiongroup` AS `og` ON o.group = og.id
WHERE (e.id = 3 or e.id IS NULL)
    AND (e2.product = p.id or e2.product IS NULL)
    AND (og.id = 1)
GROUP BY `o`.`id`
```

How can i make this query correct?
it now checks if it can find any of the specifications. but it has to check if each specgroup of the edition is either qualified and correct or null.

[Click here for Database design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z9eb2.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure but something like this could work

```
SELECT o.* FROM Options o, Edition e WHERE SELECT GROUP_CONCAT( o.Specification, ',') IN (GROUP_CONCAT(e.Specification, ','))
```

Maybe you Need subselect for the group_concats or for sorting them. But this could actually do the trick, since all specs in o have to be in the Edition specs.

But as i said, i am not sure

Comment: Jep that's works after some small changes in the syntax. The final result is as follow:
`WHERE (e.id = 3 or e.id IS NULL)
    AND (e2.product = p.id or e2.product IS NULL)
    AND (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(os.specification, ',') = 
    (GROUP_CONCAT(es.specification, ',')))
    AND (og.id = 1)`